# Как реализовать в запросе elasticsearch поиск слова по полю с логикой учёта ошибок английской раскладки

Tags: c#, запрос, elasticsearch, elastic

Пример: ввожу "ckjdj", оно меняется на "слово". Есть ли такая возможность в ES?

Comment: вы через C# хотите это сделать? зачем тут этот тэг?

Comment: В Elasticsearch нет встроенной функциональности для учета ошибок ввода слов с другой раскладкой. Однако, эту задачу можно решить с помощью создания индексов с альтернативными вариантами слов и поиска по ним. Вам также может понадобиться использовать плагины транслитерации, например, ICU Analysis